# npm install packery - and its dependecies

Tags: node.js, npm, packery

I am trying to install packery - but I am getting issues

npm install packery --save

it then adds the node module

but when I run gulp it comes up with the error

: Cannot find module './rect' from '/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/packery/dist'

do I do something like this?

```
  "packery-shim" : {
    "packery" : {
      "depends" : {
        "item" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/item.js",
        "packer" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/packer.js",
        "packery" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/packery.js",
        "rect" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/rect.js"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how would I add the dependencies for packery to avoid this error

Comment: something like this?  
  "packery-shim" : {
    "packery" : {
      "depends" : {
        "item" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/item.js",
        "packer" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/packer.js",
        "packery" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/packery.js",
        "rect" : "./node_modules/packery/dist/js/rect.js"
      }
    }
  }